# Prevent background scrolling with t&c's box open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As soon as you open my website, you are greeted with a T&C's and GDPR modal box [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnuDe.jpg). However, the background still scrolls when this is open, I have tried code to stop the scrolling, but that prevents scrolling across the whole website. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**[OUR WEBSITE](http://s2br5s5r3.gb-02.live-paas.net/)**

---

```
html,body.modal-open { 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.allowScroll {
  overflow: scroll !important;
}
```

---

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".termsagree").on("click", function() {
    $("html, body.model-open").addClass("allowScroll");
  });
});
```

**EDIT** Once you click agree the pop up won't show again unless you reload the website in another incognito page!

Comment: @NullPointer I am using WP Pop Up plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the css selector "modal-open" on your website but maybe something like this would work?

Replace your example code with this.

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    if($('#tlight').length){
        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    } 
});
```

From the looks of it, once you click the agree button the page reloads and removes the '#tlight' element from the DOM. So what this will do is check if it exists on page load, and if it does set body overflow to hidden. You may need to add "important" to it depending on your current CSS.

Comment: Thank you! I just found `modal-open` online and thought that's what my T&C's modal box was called? Are you able to find out what it is called from my website please?? Just so that I am able to apply it to your code. I have tried using `tbrightcontent` as I believe that is the modal's name but I am not sure.

Comment: Hello, I have tried you code but I can't get it to work, I have tried replacing `modal-open` with multiple class names related to the modal open box. Would you be able to go on the website and try and find it please as I am unable to :(

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: `'body'` didn't work so I changed it to `'html'` and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.